# Как получить записи из смежной таблицы Laravel в один запрос

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, запрос, eloquent

Подскажите пожалуйста, как мне сделать запрос в БД, через связь.
Получается я ищу из модели Продукты записи - по названию, но также хочу при поиске "названия категории" - получать записи, относящиеся к ним.

```
$search - получаю поисковую строку из метода get

$products = Product::with('categories')->where(function($query) use ($search){
                $query->where('title','LIKE',"%$search%")
                ->leftjoin('categories', 'category.title', 'LIKE',"%$search%");
            })->get();
```

я может неправильно использую leftjoin , т.к. не уверен что это правильно

Answer (score 1):

```
Product::leftjoin('categories', 'categories.id', '=', 'products.category_id')
->where(function ($query) use ($search) {
    $query->where('products.title','LIKE', "%$search%")
    $query->orWhere('categories.title', 'LIKE', "%$search%");
})->get();
```

Как-то так

Comment: @Bинсентэ - спасибо, поиск теперь производится т.к. нужно)) Но есть одно "но" - при запросе названия категории - название продуктов(которые находятся) меняются на название категории )